# Is $(\mathbb{N}, x^y)$ a monoid?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, monoid

Is $A = (\mathbb{N}, x^y)$ a monoid or a group?

I think the identity element in $A$ is $e = 1$. So it should be a monoid but 
I know it can't be a group as the inverse $a$ of is $0$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Recall that $e$ is an identity for the operation $\ast$ if $x\ast e=e\ast x=x$ for all $x$. Now certainly $x^1=x$ for all $x$. But it is not true that $1^x=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: ok .. it means that its not even monoid ?? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Hint: $2^{\left(1^2\right)} = 2 \neq 4 = (2^{1})^2$.

Comment: It is not a monoid for two reasons. As pointed out above, there is no identity. Furthermore, the operation $x\ast y=x^y$ is not associative.

Comment: can you please explain how it is not associative ? @AndréNicolas

Comment: @SubhamTripathi: See Random Jack's comment.

Comment: $(2^3)^3 = 8^3 = 512$ while $2^{(3^3)}=2^{27}$ is much bigger.

Comment: The best you can say about it is that it is a [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)).

Comment: thanks to all. as @RandomJack was the first one to say that its not a subgroup. please put it as your answer and i will accept. Thanks to all .

Comment: Exponentiation is not associative, so, No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x * y = x^y$. Then the structure $(\mathbb{N}, *)$ is not even a semigroup (that is, $*$ operation is not associative), and hence is not a monoid, since a monoid is a semigroup with the identity element.
To prove it, note that $$(2 * 1) * 2 = (2^1) * 2 = 2 ^ 2 = 4 \neq 2 = 2^1 = 2 * (1 ^ 2) = 2 * (1 * 2).$$

Also, as noted by André Nicolas, there is no identity element $e$ for this operation. This also shows that $(\mathbb{N}, *)$ is not a monoid. Such an algebraic structure with only one binary operation is called a magma (or a groupoid).